# How to calculate a composite function on the grid?

Tags: python, numpy, optimization, distribution, function-composition

I have two random variables, `x` is beta-distributed on the interval `[2, 6]` and `y` is uniformly distributed on the interval `[0, 1]`. For every `x` I would like to find `y` such that `CDF_x(x) = CDF_x(y)` and plot the graph. In other words I would like to get `CDF_y_inverse(CDF_x(x))`.

So far I have the following code which only plots the pdf of `x`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import beta, uniform

a, b = 2, 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
x = np.linspace(2+4*beta.ppf(0, a, b), 2+4*beta.ppf(1, a, b), 1000)

ax.plot(x, beta.pdf((x-2)/4, a, b), lw=2, color='green', alpha=0.5, label='beta pdf')
plt.show()
```

**Edit**: Assume instead of uniform distribution `y` has truncated normal distribution, otherwise the problem is trivial.

Comment: If `y` is uniformly distributed over [0,1] isn't its inverse-CDF just given by a linear function (actually just `y` itself)?

Comment: Actually you are right, the problem becomes trivial. Let me edit and put another distribution